# SQL Query Design for data validation issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, teradata

I have a fact table that contains some finance data. There is a column (VERS_NM) that defines wherther the value is "Actual" or "Current Outlook". The value for these two should always be the same but we noticed in some reports it seems incorrect. So I want to write a query to find where the actual value does not match the current outlook.

I cannot wrap my head around a way to do this.

Here is what the table looks like:
[image: table]

So to recap there will be an identical row to row 1 except the VERS_NM column will say "Actual". At least it is supposed to be, I want to find any instances where the Actual and Current Outlook don't match. Any help or ideas is much appreciated. Just a push in the right direction or some kind of plan to tackle this would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just self join the data, replacing the fields `a, b, c, d` with the fields that indicate that the rows are equivilent.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable    AS actual
INNER JOIN
  yourTable    AS outlook
    ON  actual.a = outlook.a
    AND actual.b = outlook.b
    AND actual.c = outlook.c
    AND actual.d = outlook.d
WHERE
      actual.VERS_NM  = 'Actual'
  AND outlook.VERS_NM = 'Current Outlook'
  AND actual.FINC_ACCT_METRIC_VAL <> outlook.FINC_ACCT_METRIC_VAL
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'll let you know how it works out. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you again for your input!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use `UNION`. It's more of a way to detect differences in many table fields but can work in your situation as well.

The technique is described in the article [The shortest, fastest, and easiest way to compare two tables in SQL Server: UNION!](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2004/11/10/2737.aspx) to compare two separate tables but you can analyse a single table.

Replace the fields `COL1`, `COL2` etc. with the columns you want to compare. For your comparison I've added a `WHERE` clause to the inner `SELECT` to effectively view your data as two separate tables.

```
SELECT MIN(TableName) as TableName, ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
FROM
(
  SELECT 'Actual' as TableName, A.ID, A.COL1, A.COL2, A.COL3, ...
  FROM Finance_Data A
  WHERE VERS_NM = 'Actual'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Outlook' as TableName, B.ID, B.COL1, B.COl2, B.COL3, ...
  FROM Finance_Data B
  WHERE VERS_NM = 'Current Outlook'
) T
GROUP BY ID, COL1, COL2, COL3 ...
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `group by` all other columns, and then use a `having` clause to demand that each group has an "Actual" and a "Current outlook" variant:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
group by
        col1
,       col2
,       ... all other columns ...
having  sum(case when VERS_NM = 'Actual' then 1 end) <> 1
        or sum(case when VERS_NM = 'Current Outlook' then 1 end) <> 1
        or count(*) <> 2
```

Comment: The OP wants results where two matching rows exist (one actual, one outlook), but with different values.